# How to access db in vps

Tags: java, mysql, linux, deployment, vps

Hi in order to access the db on my vps i have to previosly connect via ssh I have tested this with MySQL WORKBENCH and it works. 
But Netbeans (working ide) does no provide ssh connection when creating a db connection so I cannot connect my local application to my new server.
How can I go around this?
How can i set my jta datasource to deal with this?

Thank you very much
Best Regards
Ignacio

Comment: Is there something in the order of ip@user;pass:port that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to archive connectivity from netbeans:

1. **REALLY UNSAFE Method:** Make MySql listen on the network-interface connected to the internet. Set *bind-address* in your mysql-configuration file to 0.0.0.0 and mysql will listen on all interfaces. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address You can then access MySql from everywhere on the internet. 
    *Remember: This is a serious security vulnerability! Search Google and you will find a lot of articles explaining in great detail why.*
2. **Safe method:** SSH can do port-forwarding. It means, that one port on your local machine listens for connections and tunnels all traffic well encrypted to the remote port. On linux this is done with `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 YOUR_SERVERS_IP`. You can then access your MySql-Server on localhost:3306 like it is running on your local computer (just slower). On Windows Putty can be configured to do the same thing. I don't remember exactly where, but in the dialog where you setup your connection (before the command-prompt) you also can configure port-forwarding.
3. Write an application to run on your server, which takes care of Authorization and exposes and API to users (like the Youtube-api for example, which has some public methods but also some requiring authentication). This could be done in numerous different ways like XMLRPC (using a webserver and some web-application) or a custom protocol. This is probably the one most suitable for production use.

Comment: 2 is the way to go but it is not working yet, I'm connecting to linux from winwods via putty, but the commands says it is already in use, but when i try to connect from netbeans it fails

Comment: @Ignacio that sounds like you have something running on that port, our your configuration is not working. If you have any other service running on that vps (like a web-server), try redirecting that. If that works something is wrong with MySql (only listening on a socket? See if "skip-networking" is enabled..), if it doesn't, your configuration is wrong.

Comment: you where right but now diff problem, please look at new question if possible, thank you very Muchhh

Answer (score 0):

Poke some holes in your firewall to let NetBeans connect?

I would recommend you simply copy the database to your development environment and don't touch the VPS unless you're ready to 'release'.

Comment: But when I realse my app will need to connect to that the db in the vps through ssh (unless I correct the issue now).

Comment: should I ask my admin to open 3306 in the firewall, and that should do it?